# VBA String sanitation

Tags: string, vba, excel

I get data imported from an Oracle database and use Excel to create some reports from that.  Recently one of our data entry folks has started beginning her entries with "+".  Excel than evaluates that and adds = then displays the dreaded ?name# error.  The error is error 2029.

I tried using

```
If IsError(C.Value) Then
    C.Value = Replace(C.Value, "=+", "", 1, -1, vbTextCompare)
End If
```

But that isn't getting me anywhere.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the data in a text/CSV file then you can try: `Data > Import External Data > Import Data` This launches a wizard which lets you specify specific columns as text and that causes symbols like +, - etc not to be parsed by Excel

In VBA this can be done through the `Worksheet("foo").QueryTables.Add` method. There are quite a few options but the `TextFileColumnDataTypes` property lets you specify which columns to treat as text. It might be easier to work out what is happening by recording a macro of the wizard being used and then editing that to suit

If you're reading in the data more directly (e.g. via ADO or DAO) then just make sure the destination cell is in text format before the data is added

`Worksheet("foo").Cells(r, c).NumberFormat = "@"`

---

NB in your original solution, you almost certainly wanted to look at `C.Formula` rather than `C.Value` If a cell C had a formula of `=123+456` then `C.Value` would be 579 whereas `C.Formula` would be `=123+456`

+1 on using the built-in `Replace` method in this context

Comment: Thank you barrowc,
your final answer turned the trick, I forgot about looking at the .formula rather than the .value

Answer (score 2):

Excel has it's own replace function:

```
ActiveSheet.Cells.Replace What:="=+", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
```

Comment: When I run that I get runtime error '438'  obeject dosen"t support this property or method

Comment: oops - try again with the "Cells" - which returns a range object of all the cells in the worksheet

Answer (score 0):

Just one other thing too, it should be:

```
If IsError(C.Value) Then
    C.Value = Replace(C.Formula, "=+", "", 1, -1, vbTextCompare)
End If
```

This is because the =+ is stored in the formula property, not the value...You can assign the replace(...) to C.Value or C.Formula if you don't want to do the cleanup yourself in VBA